# PHP ajax Calendar doesnt display the next month when click next & previous?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, calendar

This is the code Jquery code in which i get the current datetime as time() and then set it to currentDate value

```
function getNextMonth(nextMonth)
{
    var currentDate     = $('#currentDate').val();
    if(currentDate =='')
    {
        currentDate = 0;;
    }
    else
    {
        currentDate = $('#currentDate').val();;
    }
    var billingStatus   = $('#billingStatus').val();
    var userId          = $('#userId').val();

    var data = {
                currentDate: currentDate,
                billingStatus: billingStatus,
                userId: userId,
                nextMonth: nextMonth
            };
            console.log(data); 
            //alert($('#currentDate').val());
        $.ajax({
                url: $('#site_url').val() + 'people/timesheet/set_date',    
                type: 'POST',
                data: data,
                success: function(theResponse){
                    console.log(theResponse);
                //alert(theResponse);
                    $('.monthlyWrap').html(theResponse);
                    $('#monYear').html($('#monthYear').val());
                    //$('#topLoadingWrap').hide();
                    //notify('Log Time deleted successfully!', 'success')
                }
            }); 
}
```

and this is the code to process the data from the currentDate value

```
<div class="monthlyWrap">
   <?php
        //$timestamp = strtotime('next Sunday');

        $days = array();

        $month_start = (date('N', strtotime('01-'.$currentMonth, $currentDate))+1)%8;
        $monthSt= (date('N', strtotime('00-'.$currentMonth)));
        $date = $currentDate;
        $day = date('d', $date) ;
        $month = date('m', $date);
        $year = date('Y', $date) ;
        $days_in_month = cal_days_in_month(0, $month, $year) ; 

        $weeks = ceil(($monthSt + $days_in_month) / 7);
        $yr = date('Y', $date) ;
        $mon = date('m', $date) ;

        //$test= date('m/d/Y h:i:s a', time());


        for ($year = $yr; $year <= $yr; $year++){
            for ($month = $mon; $month <= $mon; $month++){

                $firstday = date("w", mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, 1, $year));
                $lastday = date("t", mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, 1, $year));

                $no_of_weeks = 1;
                $count_weeks = 0;
                while($no_of_weeks <= ($lastday+$firstday)){

                    $no_of_weeks += 1;
                    $count_weeks++;
                }
                //echo "Number Of weeks in Month=$month Year=$year = $count_weeks <br>";
                //echo "firstday=$firstday lastday=$lastday no_of_weeks = $no_of_weeks <br>";
            }
        } 

        if($count_weeks == 5)
        {
            $totalColumn = 40;
        }
        else
        {
            $totalColumn = 48;
        }
        $k=1;
        $i=1;
        $c=1;
        $currentDay =0;
        $total_hours ='';
        $total_minutes ='';

        for ($j = 1; $j <= $totalColumn; $j++) 
        {
            if($i%8 == 0)
            {
                ?>
                <div class="daysOfMonth" style="border-right:1px solid #DDDDDD;">
                    <div style="float:left;padding:40px 30px">
                    <?php 
                        if($total_hours ==0)
                        {
                            echo '';
                        }
                        else
                        {

                            $tot_min = intval($total_minutes/60);
                            $total_remain = intval($total_minutes%60);
                            if($total_remain==0)
                            {
                                $total_remain ='00';
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                $total_remain =$total_remain ;
                            }
                            echo $total_hours+$tot_min.':'.$total_remain;
                        }
                    ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <?php 
            }
            else
            {
                if($j>=$month_start && $k<=$days_in_month)
                {

                    $month_start_day = strtotime('01-'.$currentMonth);
                    $days[] = strftime('%a', $month_start_day);
                    $month_start_day = strtotime('+1 day', $month_start_day);

                    if($currentDay ==0)
                    {
                        $currentDay = (date('N', $month_start_day) + $currentDay );
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $currentDay = (date('N', $month_start_day) +$k-1)%7  ;
                    }

                    if($currentDay == 0 || $currentDay==1)
                    {
                        $backgroundColor = 'background-color: #E7ECF0;';
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $backgroundColor = '';
                    }


                    ?>
                    <div class="daysOfMonth" style="border-right:1px solid #DDDDDD;<?=$backgroundColor?>"><?=$k;?>
                    <div style="float:left;width:80px;height:60px;overflow:hidden">
                        <?php

                        $currentDateMonthYear   = date('Y-m', $date) ;
                        $orgId                  = $this->session->userdata('CCINTORGID');
                        $userType   = $this->session->userdata('CCINTUTYPE');
                        if($userType == 'SUPER_ADMIN' || $userType == 'ADMIN' || $userType == 'OWNER' )
                        {
                            $hoursDetail    = $this->timesheet_model->get_montly_timesheet($orgId, $currentDateMonthYear, $userId, $billingStatus);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $loggedInId     = $this->session->userdata('CCINTUID');
                            $hoursDetail    = $this->timesheet_model->get_montly_timesheet($orgId, $currentDateMonthYear, $userId, $billingStatus, $loggedInId);
                        }

                        if($i==9 || $i==17 || $i==25 || $i==33 || $i==41)
                        {
                            $total_hours =' ';
                            $total_minutes ='';
                        }
                        if($hoursDetail)
                        {
                            $hours = '';
                            $minutes ='';
                            foreach($hoursDetail as $row)
                            {
                                //print $row['hours'];
                                $hoursDate =  $row['date'];
                                $hoursDay = date('d', strtotime($hoursDate)) ;
                                if($hoursDay==$k)
                                {
                                        ?>
                                        <div class="hoursDiv"><?php //echo $hours[$k] 
                                            if($hoursDay==$k)
                                            {
                                                //$hours += $row['hours'];
                                                $time = explode(':', $row['hours']);
                                                $hours  += $time[0];
                                                $minutes +=  $time[1];

                                            }
                                            else
                                            {
                                                echo $hours ='';
                                                echo $minutes ='';
                                            }
                                            ?>
                                        </div>
                                        <?php
                                }
                            }
                            if($hours !=0 || $minutes !=0)
                            {
                                if($minutes==0)
                                {
                                    $minutes ='00';
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    $minutes =$minutes ;
                                }
                                echo '<div style="padding:20px 30px">'.$hours.':'.$minutes.'</div>';
                            }

                            $total_hours = $hours + $total_hours;
                            $total_minutes = $minutes + $total_minutes;
                        }
                    ?>
                    </div>  
                    </div>
                    <?php
                    $k++;
                    $currentDay++;
                }
                else
                {
                    ?>
                    <div class="daysOfMonth" style="border-right:1px solid #DDDDDD;">&nbsp;</div>
                    <?php
                }
            }
            $i++;

        }
        ?>
        <div class="daysOfMonth" style="border-top:0px;border-right:1px solid #DDDDDD;float:right;margin-right:1px;height:97px">
            <div style="padding:35px 30px">
            <?php 
                if((isset($totalHours['totalHours'])) || isset($totalHours['totalMinutes']))
                {
                    if($totalHours['totalMinutes']==0)
                    {
                        $totalMin ='00';
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $totalMin =$totalHours['totalMinutes'] ;
                    }
                    $totalMin = intval($totalMin/60);
                    $totalRemain = intval($total_minutes%60);
                    if($totalRemain==0)
                    {
                        $totalRemain ='00';
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $totalRemain =$totalRemain ;
                    }
                    print $totalHours['totalHours']+$totalMin.':'.$totalRemain;
                }

            ?>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div style="float:right;padding:40px 30px">Total Hours</div>
        <input type="hidden" name="currentDate" id="currentDate" value="<?=$currentDate?>" />
        <input type="hidden" name="monthYear" id="monthYear" value="<?=$monthYear?>" />
</div>
```

So when i click next it doesn't display the next month (i.e) Feb can someone help me !

Comment: any console error you get?

Comment: @Ankur , No i didnt get any console error

Comment: @Ankur , When i click "Next" this is the data that has been passed to the php code " Object {currentDate: "1422687295", billingStatus: "ALL", userId: "0", nextMonth: "NEXT"}"

Comment: check in console next ajax call.in response what is return? is there any error or any data?

Comment: @Ankur it return the the calendar for the current month and there is no error

Comment: @AnkurBhadania check this link, this the response from the ajax call http://pastebin.com/xaz1yTZ7 and it return data without any year but i have doubt whether there is any error in calculation in php code

Comment: check the response as you say you getting current month data on next button call not next month data. check you ajax php file

Comment: @AnkurBhadania, there is no error in getting the output and the help is that i couldn't get the next month (i.e) the next month is feb but it display march and previous month should be dec for jan but it display jan again(2 times)

Comment: if you get current month data on next call so no effect display because data will be same

Comment: @AnkurBhadania, i have not idea how to sort this out can you help me ?

Comment: @AnkurBhadania no i get the next month data only but i could never get the feb 2015 and then may 2015 is repeating 2 times and instead of feb 2015 it display jan 2015 data 2 times

Comment: @AnkurBhadania i get the current month data and then process it to get next month data by using the php code

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer by adding the value of **(28*24*60*60)** to **currentDate** :D